# How to reference cell "A(x.Value)" where x is an Integer that goes from 1 until "A(x.Value)" = NULL

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I am trying to run through a column in an Excel sheet and search through column A until it finds the first cell that is empty in column A. I need to do it by using a variable x, where x starts at 1 and increases after each run of the loop.

Ideally, I would like to do something like:

Workbooks("Name1").Sheets(2).Range("A.(x.Value)")

but I do not think this will work and am not sure how to do this correctly as I am not too familiar with VBA. Wondering if anyone can help me out with a way to do this, if it is even possible. I have the loops created that I need, I am only having difficulties referencing the cell defined by an integer.

Here is a piece of what I have set up:

```
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim z As Integer
    Dim status As Boolean

    x = 13
    y = 2
    z = 2

   If Workbooks("Training_TEST").Sheets(2).Range("A(x.Value)") = Null Then
            status = False
        Else
            status = True

   End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integers are not Objects in VBA.

> If Workbooks("Training_TEST").Sheets(2).Range("A" & x) = Null Then

You should watch [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=KHO5NIcZAc4&index=1&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) video series on YouTube.

Here are some relevant videos:

- [Excel VBA Introduction Part 8 -
  Variables](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=N1mADWqzWy4&index=8&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)
- [Excel VBA Introduction Part 9 - Object
  Variables](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=7Ugoj7hpUEA&index=9&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)
- [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells,
  Activecell, End,
  Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: That makes sense why I was having trouble then. Thanks for the help and the suggestion!